# Radio Button toggle Selection if Different Radio Button is Selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

I am trying to setup a some radio buttons were there will be options and then a auto delivery button. What I am trying to do is when the selection is clicked then step 2 if click the auto delivery is clicked it will select the auto delivery option.

```
        <table class="table">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align: middle; border: none;">
                    <input class="big" id="1bot" type="radio" name="itemChoice" value="">
                </td>
                <td style="vertical-align: middle; border: none;">
                    <p><span>1 bottles</span></p>
                </td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align: middle; border: none;">
                    <input class="big auto" type="checkbox" name="auto" value="">
                </td>
                <td style="vertical-align: middle; border: none;">
                    <p><span>Auto</span></p>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align: middle; border: none;">
                    <input class="big" id="bot1auto" type="radio" name="" value="">
                </td>
                <td style="vertical-align: middle; border: none;">
                    <p><span>Auto Delivery Confirmed!</span></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Here is where I am jQuery wise.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$('input[type=radio][name=auto]').change(function() {
    var autoYes = $('.auto').prop( "checked", true );
    var autoNo = $('.auto').prop( "checked", false );
    if ( ( autoYes && $('input[type=radio][name=1bot]').prop('checked',true) ) ) {
            $('#bot1auto').prop('checked', true);
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

So I would like to have it toggle depending if the auto delivery box is checked or not

Comment: You aren't using radio buttons correctly. give them all the same `name` attribute and you don't need any JS to accomplish what you are trying to do. [MDN Radio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio)

Comment: That doesn't do anything. I need the JS to check the radio box and then if checked when auto delivery is clicked, to get that check true or false and if true click the auto confirm button